# Can we delete the label and repack it during second time code runs PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

```
                    if bool(suggestion_label.winfo_ismapped()):
                    suggestion_label.destroy()
                else:
                    suggestion_label.pack()
```

I wanted to ask that anything i do the label packs on the screen and its not deleted **second time PART** of the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `destroy` on a widget, it's gone and can't be used again.

If you want to hide and reveal it, use `pack_forget` instead of `destroy`. Be aware that `pack` is dependent on the order it's called. Re-packing the widget may not put it back in the same place unless you explicitly use the `before` or `after` options.

If you use `grid`, it has a `grid_remove` function where it will remember where it was replaced. Calling `grid` with no arguments will restore it with the same grid settings.

Comment: how to use before or after opitions?

Comment: and i dont know why neither destroy nor pack_forget is working